making a long lasting battery pack for 24V/0.5A
I brought a stereo equipment from Japan that uses a wall-wart set at 24V/0.5A.
I would like to replace the PS with a long-lasting battery pack, but all I can find are 12V/5A batteries, or 24V/5A. I do not want to ruin the equipment by having too much current on tap. How can I wire 12V batteries to give me a long-lasting PS w/o overpowering my sensitive equipment?
Thanks in advance!

5Ah batteries means they will run the equipment for about 10 hours if it draws 0.5A. Chances are the actual average draw is a fair bit less than 0.5A.

Would those be 5 Ah batteries per chance?

Just use the 5 Ah batteries.  The stereo will only draw whatever current it requires.  The 5 Ah batteries will not force excess current into the stereo.
